# Does a raise include more stock options?

Tags: raise, startup

I work at a startup, and I'm want to ask for the first raise since I started. I was hired with a base pay and ok stock options (1 year cliff, 4 year vesting). My stock has not all vested yet.

If I ask for an n% raise does that include both salary and stock, or just salary? If a raise includes stock what are the details (does it vest with my existing stock/independently, price, etc.)?

Comment: Just be more explicit when communicating.

Answer (score 2):

Just salary though depending on your arrangement with your employer, there may be additional stock and/or stock options granted. Don't forget that another portion of your options will vest each year and thus become something that could be exercised which is why some companies may issue options on various schedules in some cases. Each issuance of stock and options would have its own terms dictated by the plan of that company as there can be various vesting schedules where some companies may vest 20% a year for 5 years while others may do 25% a year for 4 years as a couple of possible examples of how a company can encourage one to stay with a company for years as the options may take time to vest each year.